# Saving data outside function in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller

I want to get data outside my function.

**mycode :**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ParameterCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = null;
    fireCompoment.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
      $scope.data = snapshot.val();
      console.log($scope.data); // HERE DATA = SOMEDATA
    });
    console.log($scope.data); // HERE DATA = NULL
  });
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: looks like you have a syntax error going on in your first log statement

Comment: Are you sure your goes into the firecompoment..?

Comment: yes sure, i read it on console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep that in mind: Javascript is always synchronous and single-threaded. When you make a AJAX call and `console.log($scope.data)`, it happens at the same time.
What you can do is wrapping the `console.log($scope.data)` into a function to make is asynchronous.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ParameterCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = null;
  fireCompoment.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    $scope.data = snapshot.val();
    console.log($scope.data); // HERE DATA = SOMEDATA
    printData();
  });

  function printData() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check `$q.defer();` in angularJs, fireCompoment.on() goes in asynchronous so you will get resolve and promise with the use of `$q` service.

hope it will help you.